# media9: artefacts in embedded movie and looping inconsistent

Tags: beamer, media9

I'm really having trouble to play back movies consistently, and I'm not sure where my workflow fails.

Usually desired behavior:

- one slide with a still of the first movie frame. I would tell the audience what to expect.
- movie starts playing after I click with my presenter and then loops until I go to the next slide

To achieve this, I manually take a snapshot of the first frame, and put it on one slide, then build the very same slide again, but with the movie instead of the snapshot and the option `autoplay = true`. I know it's not pretty, but I was not able to get movies to start consistently on mouseclick and with this workflow I get the desired behavior most of the time.

Nevertheless, I continue to have trouble with looping the movies. Sometimes, the movie just *won't loop* but stop after one run. Sometimes, the movie will loop, but there will be heavy *artifacts from the second run on*. Compiling the same document multiple times will produce different behavior. This is really a dealbreaker, because I cannot even rely on the fact that a movie that I got working will continue to work, I have to check every single movie after each compile which is of course very tiring.

I'm seeing the same issues with a number of different movies, not just with this one. Most common artifact is for the movie to turn into a green hue, but I have also seen pink, red and yellow stripes - or sometimes red lettering spelling the filenames of the included .tex files - which I doubt is coming from the movie itself, but looks more like a pdftex issue.

Source code, pdf, movie files and screenshot of the artifacts here:
https://cloud.mpi-cbg.de/index.php/s/wqZ2Xx3kmI17XZZ
When I play the pdf on my system, it loops but has artifacts in the 2nd run.

The example movie was downloaded from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytqJjpdsNi8
then converted to h.264 using the "Handbrake" tool (I think it's essentially a GUI frontend for the ffmpeg codecs)

- Mac OS X 10.11.6
- TeX Live 2016
- media9 0.76
- Adobe Reader 15.23.20056.213124 (I know it's oldish, but every time I update Adobe Reader, something else in the videos breaks)

Conference talk is on Monday, so *any help* is highly appreciated ...

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English spell check
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % utf8 support, also \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for graphics, subfigures etc., option pdftex is needed for incorporation of .pdf files
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{tikz}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % Turn off navigation bar at the bottom

\mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}   
    \usecolortheme{seagull}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Optical projection tomography on fixed samples}\begin{center}
        \vspace*{-1mm}\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=8.2cm]{Mouse.png}
\end{center}\end{frame}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\begin{frame}{Optical projection tomography on fixed samples}\begin{center}
    \vspace*{-1mm}\includemedia[activate=pageopen,deactivate=pageclose,width=12cm, height=8.2cm,addresource=Mouse.mp4,
    flashvars={src=Mouse.mp4 &playbutton=none &loop=true &autoPlay=true}]{\includegraphics{Mouse.png}}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
\end{center}\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with `beamer`

Comment: In fact, there is some issue with `Mouse.mp4`. It doesn't loop well in recent FlashPlayer versions. I will re-encode it using `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`playbutton` is not a Flash variable of the player (Strobe) but an option to `\includemedia`.

The code produces a document in "presenter mode", as requested in the OP, for situations without access to a mouse. The still image is on the slide before the video. The video is loaded and auto-started when passing to the slide containing it. The example uses plain `VPlayer.swf` instead of Strobe.

If a mouse is accessible, playback can be controlled as follows:
Press the mouse button over the running video in order to pause it. Give further explanations to the audience, if desired. Release mouse button to continue playback.

---

The `handbrake` (odd name for a media encoder, btw) encoded video does not loop well. This could be fixed by re-encoding it using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i Mouse.mp4 -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 30 -r 30 Mouse1.mp4
```

---

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English spell check
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % utf8 support
%\usepackage{graphicx} % for graphics, subfigures etc., option pdftex is needed for incorporation of .pdf files
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{tikz}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % Turn off navigation bar at the bottom

\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}    
  \usecolortheme{seagull}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Optical projection tomography on fixed samples}
  \begin{center}
  \only<1>{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Mouse.png}}
  \only<2>{\includemedia[
    width=0.8\linewidth,
    playbutton=none,
    activate=pageopen,
    addresource=Mouse1.mp4,
    passcontext, %enable right-click menu 
    flashvars={
      source=Mouse1.mp4&
      loop=true&
      autoPlay=true
    }
  ]{\includegraphics{Mouse.png}}{VPlayer9.swf}}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm still seeing some artifacts when I download your movie & code from sharelatex and compile it locally :(
Also, with your solution, I need to click _into_ the video to play. I usually give presentations with a presenter/laserpointer, standing a couple of steps away from the computer. Going back to the computer and finding the mouse to click into the video is awkward. That means I need the video to play upon a mouseclick anywhere on the slide, because that's the only signal the presenter can send (i.e. "forward one slide"). That's why I used the workaround with the extra slide ...

Comment: I see. I will edit the answer to insert the "presenter" version. Concerning the artifacts, of which kind are they? Would you please try to update to the most recent Flash-Player plugin version?

Comment: I just updated Flash Player to 25.0.0.127, but now the video doesn't loop anymore ...

Comment: Artifacts: (also edited in the original post, and screenshot uploaded to the owncloud folder) Most common artifact is for the movie to turn into a green hue, but I have also seen pink, red and yellow stripes - or sometimes red lettering spelling the filenames of the included .tex files - which I doubt is coming from the movie itself, but looks more like a pdftex issue?

Comment: Even with `Mouse1.mp4`?  Did you remove `playbutton=none` from the Flash vars? I will run further tests this evening at home.

Comment: so I removed `playbutton=none` from the flashvars. If I use your code with your re-encoded file, the movie does not loop. If I use my code and your file, the movie loops once and then stops. But in the first loop, I again see the green artifacts. I'm just re-installing ffmpeg and will also try again to re-encode (since I have more movies, and I cannot keep comping back to you for everyone I need re-encoded ;) ).

Comment: I tested under Windows-7, FP 25.0.0.127, AR-DC 2015.023.20070, video file `Mouse1.mp4`. Apart from `autoPlay` not working, the video loops and does not display any artifacts. The `autoPlay` issue could be avoided by using the older `VPlayer9.swf`.

Comment: Mkay. Have you tried the .pdf you compiled, or the one I did (updated version in the owncloud link)? I recompiled, now have a looping video again & artifacts. I don't have Windows here, will have to try at the PC at work tomorrow. But in the end I need it to run on Mac, because that's the laptop I have and will take. Any other ideas what I could check?

Comment: Your `Test.pdf`, as contained in the zip-file, works for me. In fact, there *are* some artifacts, but these originate from the tomography method and are visible in the original YT video.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56611/discussion-between-alexg-and-wiebke).